# loading spinner from url using json

Tags: android, json, url, spinner

I am trying to load spinner values from url using json.

The code I'm using is

```
 private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            // Locate the WorldPopulation Class 
            world = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
            // Create an array to populate the spinner 
            worldlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            // JSON file URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://");

        //  Log.v("Load Employees",jsonobject.toString());

            try 
            {
                // Locate the NodeList name
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("Employees");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) 
                {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    WorldPopulation worldpop = new WorldPopulation();

                    worldpop.setRank(jsonobject.optString("FirstName"));
                    worldpop.setCountry(jsonobject.optString("LastName"));
                    worldpop.setPopulation(jsonobject.optString("EmpNo"));
                    //      worldpop.setFlag(jsonobject.optString("flag"));
                    world.add(worldpop);

                    // Populate spinner with country names
                    worldlist.add(jsonobject.optString("FirstName") + "-" +jsonobject.optString("EmpNo"));

                    mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(VisitorEntry.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  worldlist));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            { 
                //  Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This code displays result sometimes and doesn't display sometime. I am not understanding the issue and want to know if there is some other way to fetch values from url into spinner.
The time when i am not getting displayed with the values, I get the following errors:

```
04-27 14:19:25.979: W/System.err(17486): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
04-27 14:19:25.979: W/System.err(17486):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4611)
04-27 14:19:25.979: W/System.err(17486):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:867)
04-27 14:19:25.979: W/System.err(17486):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
04-27 14:19:25.979: W/System.err(17486):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10271)
04-27 14:19:25.979: W/System.err(17486):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10226)
04-27 14:19:25.979: W/System.err(17486):    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.resetList(AbsSpinner.java:153)
04-27 14:19:25.979: W/System.err(17486):    at android.widget.AbsSpinner.setAdapter(AbsSpinner.java:104)
04-27 14:19:25.979: W/System.err(17486):    at android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(Spinner.java:382)
04-27 14:19:25.989: W/System.err(17486):    at com.example.wepvms.VisitorEntry$DownloadJSON1.doInBackground(VisitorEntry.java:854)
04-27 14:19:25.989: W/System.err(17486):    at com.example.wepvms.VisitorEntry$DownloadJSON1.doInBackground(VisitorEntry.java:1)
04-27 14:19:25.989: W/System.err(17486):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-27 14:19:25.989: W/System.err(17486):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-27 14:19:25.989: W/System.err(17486):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-27 14:19:25.989: W/System.err(17486):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-27 14:19:25.989: W/System.err(17486):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-27 14:19:25.989: W/System.err(17486):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-27 14:19:25.989: W/System.err(17486):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: You can Use Volley for the same

Comment: jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://");  is it the url address from which you are trying to fetch data ?

Comment: Yes. I have a url which iam using and iam able to fetch the values properly. @Haroon

Comment: better you try with volley

Comment: please check the post again, I have pasted my error code when the values are not displayed @Aditya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest try to put

```
mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(VisitorEntry.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  worldlist));
```

this inside `runonUiThread` like this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {

mySpinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(VisitorEntry.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,  worldlist));

    }
});
```

Comment: glad to help you Happy Coding :)

Comment: if url is different then you need to make it seprate

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can use Arraylist for stroing data than create Baseadapter class
for display data..

Comment: can you suggest me with some code or example as i don't have the knowledge on the things you are talking about @Rohit Rathore

Comment: hello    you can setadapter out side of doInBackground , set adapter in onPostExecute..

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a library [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) this make this easier to parse

you can refer [this](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/src/com/google/gson/examples/android/GsonProguardExampleActivity.java) for how he parse and add it to his List Object

Comment: Thank you. But I have to use json only. SUggest me if you know with json @Kuro

Comment: If you want to do a hardway first you need to used a HttpRequest to get a response and then parse it its much more safer than using JSONFunctions you can refer to this link http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html